# How do I write data that is not deleted with database when the form is closed and opened?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
private void btnPublish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Sqlbaglan.NesneVer().thisConn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;initial catalog = ManagerPanel;integrated security = true");
    Sqlbaglan.NesneVer().thisConn.Open();
    Sqlbaglan.NesneVer().thisQuery = new SqlCommand("SELECT Kurallar FROM [Rules] WHERE TC=@TC", Sqlbaglan.NesneVer().thisConn);
    Sqlbaglan.NesneVer().thisQuery.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TC", tbxTC.Text);

    label1.Text = Sqlbaglan.NesneVer().thisQuery.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

    Sqlbaglan.NesneVer().thisConn.Close();
}
```

Friends, I have 2 problems, I do not have much knowledge of SQL, but I wanted to do my job with the database. I created a SQL connection and query object with singleton dp. I called the rule that has that TC with the TC entered in tbxTC and printed it on label1.Text in the SAME FORM. So far, everything happens as I want. My 1st problem is that when I open and close the form, label1.Text gets reset. Consider my second problem independent of my first problem. My second problem is that I have written in capital letters already - I am nervous- I have to show it in another form. This form's name is frm2. So consider label1.text is in another form.

Comment: So are you asking how to `UPDATE` a value in the database?

Comment: I can update for the database with my method. My question is that the text I made on label1.Text in the form does not appear when I close and open the form. So, It's resetting

Comment: I don't see an `UPDATE` stamement, only a `SELECT`.

Comment: I updated it in another query. I also got it wrong. My main problem is when I change label1.Text with this button and close and open the form, label1.Text changes. Even if I set up my database connection.